# iOS JSON pass to NextViewController in TableVIewCell

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm making a weather app, and when I click the table view cell, I want to load the weather of cities in the country into a JSON file.

So I want to pass the JSON file name to the next controller, but it keeps getting nil. Any ideas?

vc1

```swift
...
// Data Transfer
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        guard let nextViewController: SecondViewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController else {
            return
        }
        guard let cell: UITableViewCell = sender as? UITableViewCell else {
            return
        }
        nextViewController.title = cell.textLabel?.text
        // error
        nextViewController.secondAssetName = country.assetName
    }
```

vc2

```swift
...
// citi weather decode But, getting nil
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let dataAsset = NSDataAsset(name: secondAssetName ?? " ") else {
            return
        }
        do {
            weathers = try jsonDecoder.decode([Weather].self, from: dataAsset.data)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is nil? `country.assetName` or `secondAssetName` variable?

Comment: `secondAssetName` is nil. but I solved problem. thanks!